# how does a 3D modeler (such as blender) pick the vertex that you click on?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, sorting

If you click on the model viewer in a 3D Modeler (such as blender or max), it will select the vertex that the mouse was over or near. How does it know which one to use efficiently? How can it use a lasso tool or circle tool efficiently? Does it use screen space  co-ordinates for the vertices or does it use simple ray tracing?
I am trying to make a simple 3D model tool (for fun) and i can't imagine how a circle tool would work. How can it pick the nearest vertex to the mouse co- ordinates without a sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to approach this problem.

1. If you have only several thousands of vertexes, it can be very fast to just iterate over all of them.
2. If you are just clicking on a vertex (or other object) in one of the views, then you can render the scene into another buffer using a different "color" for each object in the scene.  To figure out which object you clicked on, you just have to read the color from that pixel.
3. In other circumstances, you can store the vertex data in a spatial index such as an octree.

Remember: Blender is open-source, so you can just read the [source code](http://archive.blender.org/download/source-code/index.html) if you want to find out how Blender does it.

Comment: #2 is a very common approach for complex scenes; especially for selecting faces or objects. For the OP's problem, one approach among many is to render each vertex as a single pixel, then check all data in the offscreen buffer within a specific radius of the mouse coordinate, looking for the closest one; may run into quirks with very dense vertex sets, but this doesn't sound like it's an issue for this use. Remember to turn off antialiasing/multisampling for #2, and it never hurts to take extra care to double check the color channel depth.

Comment: I think `glSelectBuffer()` is not in core, which rules it out on some systems.

Comment: Oh right it used to be but was dropped at some point. I think in 3 or 4. I'm removing that comment since it's not good advice. Guess I'm rusty.

Comment: It's fine advice, because there are plenty of people still using compatibility profile, and compatibility profile will probably be supported forever on Windows, because the GL vendors are very careful to maintain support for legacy apps.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This gives me a lot to think about. I am trying to write a software render/ modeler, so speed is extremely important, more so than the quality of the models themselves.